# How can I list the most voted questions every day?

Tags: support, questions, voting, email

Is there any way that I could list the most voted questions every day or hourly from a special tag? Or how can I find these questions?

Also as I get a weekly email from Stack Exchange can I change the period to 1 day?

Comment: Oh, you want to know how to *find* the most voted questions.  Your question title sounds like you want to *have* (ask) the most voted questions yourself.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

At 10k you are given access to the [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), which include statistics for highest voted questions and answers in a period (1 day, 2 days, week, 30 days). That information is not available broken down to specific tags.

You cannot change the email frequency.

You *can* use search to get this information, however. Search for a tag with `[tagname]`, add `is:question` to only return questions then limit results to a specific date range by adding `created:yyyy-mm-dd` to the search. You can then sort the result by votes.

For example, [yesterday 432 Python questions were asked](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq+created%3A2014-11-21&tab=votes), with the highest voted question scoring 6 (as of this writing).

Also see [*How do I search?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) in the help center.

Comment: The frequency of various types of email notifications can be changed within user preferences.  It's not clear (to me, anyway) what type of email notification OP is referring to, or for that matter which you are referring to when you state "You cannot change the email frequency."

Comment: @RobertCrovella i mean the weekly email that every user get . ( not from a special tag , but all popular questions in week )

Comment: Ah, a [newsletter](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters)

Comment: @RobertCrovella the newsletter has a fixed frequency.

Comment: Actually, [there was a +11 Python question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069448/why-does-the-is-operator-say-these-methods-arent-the-same), which is very much not +3. ;) (there are also several +4/+5s)

Comment: @Doorknob: hrmz; it seems I lost the sorting on that link, and that specific question was at least at plus 6 by the time I wrote this answer. Oh, and none of the answers on that question are correct either, good thing it was closed as a dupe...